# Getting value form hex

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, hex

I working on my final project for the college, I'm building application that connects to a bluetooth scale and present the data from the scale in the application (I need to get the weight).

I built a simple app that gets data from the scale.
The values that i get are on hex, if i convert them to decimal it doesn't correspond to the real weight i see on the scale.

```
b400b0 11 0012010f 2db43c - 69.1
b400b0 2f 0012010f 2db44b - 69.2
b400b0 19 0012010f 2db45a - 69.3
b400b0 23 0012010f 2db469 - 69.4
b400b0 46 0012010f 2db478 - 69.5
b400b0 9e 0012010f 2db487 - 69.6 
b400b0 1a 0012010f 2db496 - 69.7
b400b0 1b 0012010f 2db4a5 - 69.8
b400b0 51 0012010f 2db4a5 - 69.8
b400b0 56 0112010f 2db4b4 - 69.9
b400b0 1c 0012010f 2db4c3 - 70.0
b400b0 1a 0012010f 2db4c3 - 70.0
b400b0 43 0012010f 2db4e1 - 70.2
b400b0 9a 0012010f 2db4f0 - 70.3
b400b0 58 0012010f 2dc30f - 70.4
b400b0 4b 0012010f 2dc31e - 70.5
b400b0 73 0012010f 2dc33c - 70.7
b400b0 70 0012010f 2dc35a - 70.9
b400b0 69 0012010f 2dc378 - 71.1
b400b0 1a 0012010f 2df0b4 - 76.3
```

I analysed the data and found that for every 100 grams increase, the last digit of the hexadecimal is decreasing by one, and the second digit is increasing by one.

I need to get all the values from 5kg to 100 kg. Is there some tool/algorithm that can bring me all the values in hex? or that i need to make a some dictionary like i made now?

Comment: Why are you analyzing the data? Don't you have the documentation for the scale?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of inspecting the data, you should search for the documentation for the given scale. However, to get some information:

```
b400b0 11 0012010f 2db43c - 69.1
```

**2**d**b**4**3**c, 2B3 in hexa = 691 in decimal
2**d**b**4**3**c** is a parity check (always 15 - the previous digit)

This is true for all the values you have written, for example

```
b400b0 1a 0012010f 2df0b4 - 76.3
```

2fb = 763 in decimal

Comment: Good work, Mr. Holmes :) – The second nibble seems to be the complement: 2+d=f, b+4=f, 3+c=f in hex.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I just realized that too.